# How use maps in less mixins

Tags: less

From the documentation:
[image]

I wrote:

```
#colors() {
    backgroundDarkPrimary: '#0747A6';
    backgroundMedium: '#dfe1e6';
    backgroundLight: '#ebecf0';
    backgroundLightest: '#F4F5F7';
    backgroundLightPrimary: '#D2E5FE';
    backgroundLightSuccess: '#E4FCEF';
}
```

But when I use it in a mixin I get an error:

[image]

[image]

heed help

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wrap colors in ''?

```less
/* less */

#colors() {
  background: #0747A6;
}

.mixin( @height: 40px, @background: #colors[background] ) {
  height: @height;
  background: @background;
}

div {
  .mixin;
}
```

[**codepen**](https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/xxeEbaV)

Comment: I did not understand the question.

Comment: You write `backgroundDarkPrimary: '#0747A6';` when you need `backgroundDarkPrimary: #0747A6;` - without `''`

Comment: Thank you) However, the error has not disappeared. At first I thought it was because of the sveltekit settings, I didn’t download the repository with react and less from [here](https://github.com/malithmcr/cra-with-less), then I copied your code to App.less. There, too, the same error occurred in the less file.